# Must an employer provide a break room/lunch room to its employees?

Tags: employment, canada, british-columbia

I started working in a retail store. It has no lunch room, break room, or a place where employees can sit comfortably to relax. In practice there's a storage area where people use bins to eat their meal off of, but its intended use is not for this.

Is there a law regarding this? What legal actions are possible?

Answer (score 4):

**Is there a law regarding this?**

The relevant law is the [Employment Standards Act of British Columbia](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/employment-business/employment-standards-advice/employment-standards/forms-resources/igm/esa-part-4-section-32#policy) which only requires an employer to provide meal breaks for employees but not somewhere for them to eat their meal.

> 32. (1) An employer must ensure
>
> (a) that no employee works more than 5 consecutive hours without a meal break, and
>
> (b) that each meal break lasts at least 1/2 hour.

**What legal actions are possible?**

None - unless there's a breach of, say, health and safety legislation by allowing meals to be eaten in a refuse area, but that's off-topic.